# Use arbitrary wx objects as a column in a wx.ListCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

I have a `wx.ListCtrl` that has the `wx.LC_REPORT` bit set. It has 3 columns. I want the first column to be populated with a check box for each other entry. I tried using the `ListCtrl.InsertItem` method, but it only takes one argument (`info`) and I can't find any docs as to what that argument needs to be. I've tried just passing a `wx.CheckBox` to `InsertItem` to no avail.

Is it possible to have a checkbox as an entry in a wxPython ListCtrl? If so, how would I go about doing that?

In case there's any ambiguity as to what I'm talking about, here's a picture of what I want (not sure if this is wx, but it's what I'm looking for). I want the checkboxes next to 1..5 in the No. column.

[image: list control with checkboxes]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at `wx.lib.mixins.listctrl`.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix

class TestListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.CheckListCtrlMixin, listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        listmix.CheckListCtrlMixin.__init__(self)
        listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)
        self.setResizeColumn(3)

    def OnCheckItem(self, index, flag):
        print(index, flag)

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.list = TestListCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "No.")
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, "Progress")
        self.list.InsertColumn(2, "Description")
        self.list.Arrange()
        for i in range(1, 6):
            self.list.Append([str(i), "", "It's the %d item" % (i)])        
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Test")
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.list, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know about this. What other controls will these mixins allow you to add to a plain ListCtrl?

Comment: As I recall, it can add checkbox and editable text. The others are basically effects like sorting, highlighting, automatic width etc.

Comment: @Fenikso this was exactly what I'm looking for. My only problem is that for some reason it produces an extra checkbox in the far right corner (not attached to the ListCtrl, just off by itself). Any thoughts?

Comment: @Fenikso nvm, I figured it out

Comment: The above is a great example :D If at any point you require more custom controls to be added to your listctrl, for example a progress bars or radio controls, you can also take a look at the UltimateListCtrl in the wxPython demo, it is able to handle checkbox's, the above, and much more ;)

Comment: @AWainb great tip! I did not know about that, it is missing in the wxpython docs!

Comment: Ya it took me a bit to find the appropriate [documentation](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/ultimatelistctrl_module.html) as well. ;) I'm not sure why it has been excluded from the current/new docs as it is included with wxPython at this point. My advice is to make sure to download the latest from the above link to ensure you are up to date as the bundled version is outdated and missing some newer features like column tooltips.